# DS18B20 temperature sensor not working

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor

I am new to arduino.I try to read temperature using DS18B20 temperature sensor.I connected the pins as bellow.But,When I connected 1-pin to ground and 3-pin to +5V the sensor heated and all the little lights on the UNO board turned off and it stopped working.

[image]

When I connected 3-pin to ground and 1-pin to +5V the board worked normally.But,I gives -127 as the temperature when I uploaded the bellow code.

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
// Data wire is connected to the Arduino digital pin 2
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature sensor
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

void setup(void)
{
// Start serial communication for debugging purposes
Serial.begin(9600);
// Start up the library
sensors.begin();
}
void loop(void){
// Call sensors.requestTemperatures() to issue a global temperature and Requests to all devices on the bus
sensors.requestTemperatures();
Serial.print("Celsius temperature: ");
// Why "byIndex"? You can have more than one IC on the same bus. 0 refers to the first IC on the wire
Serial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
Serial.print(" - Fahrenheit temperature: ");
Serial.println(sensors.getTempFByIndex(0));
delay(1000);
}
```

I connected with both Normal mode and Parasite mode.But, same results..

I use this:
[image]

Help me to solve the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: you have to connect the middle pin also

Comment: The topmost image shows the correct connection (with the flat side of the package facing you). It should not have heated up so I suspect you made an error. Pin 2 (the data pin) should have a pull up of about 4.7k-10k Ohm to VDD. The -127*C value just indicates that the device is not responding or functioning or you might have destroyed it during your first trial. You can use the "Tester" example that comes with the DallasTemperature library to see if the device is recognized and to print out its unique address.

Comment: Thank you for the comments...

Yes,I pulled up of 7.4k Ohm to VDD.

Comment: Your setup (as you described it) seams OK. I can not find any errors in your program. I fear the device is broken, or you bought a fake 18B20. Can you trust your seller? The device should not heat up at all, even if you reverse connect the power pins. The -127 is plausible because the device was powered with the wrong polarity and does not operate. If you power it correctly it heats up and draws much more current than it should (<4mA). That's a bad sign. Have you a spare part? Then you can try this. But if you bought fake devices, I fear that one will not work too.

Comment: I bought this from a trusted shop in the country.
I tried but I could'nt find the error.